# InvalidResourceException when trying to "ref" an event in a function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have a SAM template file that is throwing errors while doing `sam build`: `[InvalidResourceException('MyFunction', "Type of property 'Events' is invalid.")]`

First off, at the top of my file (at the same level as `Globals`) I have this event (the idea is to define a CloudWatch schedule that fires every 15 minutes and invokes a lambda):

```
Events:
  Type: Schedule
  Properties:
    Schedule: rate(15 mins)
    name: InvokeEvery15MinutesSchedule
    Description: Invoke the target every 15 mins
    Enabled: True
```

And here's what the function looks like:

```
MyFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: ./path-to-code
    Events:
      - !Ref InvokeEvery15MinutesSchedule
```

I was doing this because I saw earlier that the following syntax is valid:

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Layers:
      - !Ref Layer1
      - !Ref Layer1
```

So, I thought that if I define an event at the top level and reference it inside the lambda, it will work. I want to keep it outside of the Lambda declaration because I want this to apply to several functions.

Can someone help with what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

"Events" is a lambda source object that defines the events that trigger this function. The object describing the source of events which trigger the function.
Try this:

```
MyFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    CodeUri: ./path-to-code
    Events:
      RateSchedule:
        Type: Schedule
        Properties:
          Schedule: rate(15 mins)
          Name: InvokeEvery15MinutesSchedule
          Description: Invoke the target every 15 mins
          Enabled: True
```